# How can I get SF Pro font working properly on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, fonts

I want to use SF Pro font as the system font for Windows 10. I tried various version but all of them have something or the other missing like ":" is doesn't show up properly or volume control icons are messed up. Is there any way to get the SF Pro font working properly on windows 10?

[image: SF Pro Windows issue]

Comment: There's no legitimate way to get it working at all on Windows. It's not licensed for anything other than macOS/iOS & even then not as a user font, only in app mockups.

Comment: Is there any other font which has similar font face that can be used in WIndows 10?

Comment: Have a look at this meta post from gra[hic design. It has a list of font-matching sites - https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions/2366#2366